# MySql Replace and Regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to remove trailing letters from Building Addresses e.g. `111A`.

I  can find those patterns with:

```
Select Address from Table where Address Regexp '^[0-9]{1,6}[A-Z] '
```

However I am unsure how to or if I can include the regexp inside a Replace so that I don't have to do 10*26 different replaces e.g.

```
Update Table set Address=Replace(Address,'0A','0') where Address like '%0A %'
```

vs some sort of (which I've tried):

```
Update Table set Address=Replace(Address,regexp ([0-9]{1,6})[A-Z],\1) 
where Address Regexp '^[0-9]{1,6}[A-Z] '
```

Comment: You can find some regex replace function if you search, but it is very limited and useless. I forgot about doing this in MySQL and created a csv which I was parsing with regex in C# and created a new csv file and imported it in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have yet to find Regex Replacement but this seemed to work for now. I neglected to mention that these were full Building Address so e.g. `111A Washington St'. This is what I ended up doing:

```
Update Table set Address=
concat(
left(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Address,' ',1),CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Address,' ',1))-1),
right(Address,(CHAR_LENGTH(Address)-CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Address,' ',1))))
)
where Address Regexp '^[0-9]{1,6}[A=Z] '
```

After spending time on similar challenges like this in this project, my conclusion is that, until and unless regex is integrated into functions such as update,locate,replace that using `substring_index` and `char_length` can get you a long way.  Please see my similar solution to a follow-up question to this one here: [Replace using Locate and/.or regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535297/replace-using-locate-and-or-regex)

Answer (score 1):

> can I include the regexp inside a Replace?

No, not in MySQL. Sigh. Missing feature.

There's an extension to do this, but to install it you need to be able to control your MySQL server.  Here:  https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme

Comment: Thanks that looks like a project and a half though! I posted my temporary solution as an answer for now, the consensus seems to be no regex replace. Lots of little things in MySql I'd change as I start to get to using it more and more...

Comment: `regexp_replace` is available in MariaDB.